# how can i calculate mass of broken glass

Tags: materials, physics, edit-mode

when I do calculate mass of broken glass it only sets for one cell not for all so please how can i calculate mass for all the cells of object?

Comment: are you talking about rigid body objects? what is a "cell"?

Answer (score 1):

Select all the pieces, then go to the left side panel(t)>Physics>Calculate Mass>Glass (Broken), then select Copy from Active.